# Comparison Date with DateTime.Now in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have problem in vba in excel.
I want the function to check whether the second day of the passed date has already been or not. I know that I'm comparison two string now, i dont know how change it to date format. Here is my code fragment:

```
Dim MyDate As Date

Set Passed = Range("D2")
MyDate = Format(DateTime.Now, "DD-DD.MM.YYYY")
If MyDate < Passed Then
Passed.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
ElseIf MyDate > Passed Then
Passed.Interior.ColorIndex = 43
```

The D2 is Short Date Format (eg. 02-05.02.2021)

Comment: Is `MyDate` defined as a `String` or a `Date`? Because `Format` returns a string, which will convert to a `Date` if it's defined right, but you did not include that part of your code. You cannot use `<` or `>` on a `String` - it has to be a `Date`.

Comment: I defined MyDate as Date.... Sorry for not having this at first

Comment: It doesn't matter how the cell is formatted. If it is a *date*, it's a date. The format just defines how it is displayed to the user. If it is a date, just write if `Passed > Now` - don't apply any formatting to dates except for display reasons.

Comment: You can use `CDate` to convert a `String` to a `Date`. That seems to be your question? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions

Comment: Now that I used if I got an error: CDate (Passed) = <Type mismatch>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You convert your String data type to a Date datatype using the `CDate` function.

For example `CDate(Passed)`

You will also need to remove the Format function as that converts your `DatetTime.Now` to a String

```
If CDate(Range("D2")) > DateTime.Now() Then

   'Do Something
Else
   'Do Something else
EndIf
```

Comment: Now that I used if I got an error: CDate (Passed) = <Type mismatch>

Comment: maybe need brackets at the end of DateTime.Now()

Comment: Nope its the same error with () or without it

Comment: That leads me to believe that whatever is in Cell D2 can't be converted to a date. Open up the watch window and step through your code line by line

Comment: Yeah its problem with Passed Date. It must be in format like that 01/12/2020. How can i get date with range eg. 01-03/12/2020??

Comment: Ok i just take Passed Date as String. Remove 3 first chars and replace "." with /. Maybe not professional but working ;) And then CDate working fine.

Comment: You can't easily use a date range. A more typical approach would be to have a start date column and an end date column. You can also use custom cell formatting to display the date whatever way in which you need to.